# Hiding or Showing Filters In Certain Categories in magento

Tags: magento, attributes, categories

on our highest level category there are about 50 shop-by options, i m trying to hide attribute filter with xml code in custom layout of categories. with this code

```
<reference name="em.catalog.leftnav">
<action method="setData">
    <instruction>hide_attribute_code</instruction>
    <value>1</value>
</action>
```

But not hide filter attribute in that category, check it on image [image: http://i.imgur.com/UHrHe.png]

Answer (score 3):

in catalog.xml

```
 <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
  <catalog_category_layered translate="label">
```

follow the template ... catalog/layer/view.phtml

Open this file and made there conditions for filters to appear on frontend, by name or id

```
           <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
            <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>

                       <?php if($_filter->getName() == 'Price' || $_filter->getName() == 'Category' || $_filter->getName() == 'Manufacturer' ): ?>   
                              <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                                   <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                                   <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                               <?php endif; ?>
                       <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: im trying but not success

Comment: Worked great for me, can you post what code you tried that isn't working for you?

Comment: How can i Hide selected attributes for selected categories of products

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your extension that is reliable for layered navigation, but this should work:

```
<reference name="em.catalog.leftnav">
    <action method="hideAttributes">
        <code>hide_attribute_code</code>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Go to the file in `app/code/POOL/YOUR/MODULE/Blocks/...` that builds your filter. If your template has something like `getFilters()` you can try `echo get_class($this)` to get the correct class/file. There you have to do two things:

1.) add a new method (in this case you can set comma seperate the attribute codes)

```
public function hideAttributes($attributeCodes)
{
    $attributeCodes = array_map('trim', explode(',', $attributeCodes));
    $this->setData('hide_attributes', $attributeCodes);
}
```

2.) search for the function that collects the filters, e.g. `getFilters()` and add

```
$filterableAttributes = // some code
foreach ($filterableAttributes as $attribute) {
    if (!in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $this->getHideAttributes())) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unset the attribute name on view layer, so find this file:

```
magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml
```

edit:

```
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
        <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Options') ?></p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                <!--  add this line  start-->
                <?php if($_filter->getName() != "Color"): ?>
                <!--  add this line end-->
                <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                <?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?>
                </dd>
                <!--  add this line  start-->
                <?php endif; ?>
                <!--  add this line end-->
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope you can get working now !